# Datatable with file uploads

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable with a PrimeFaces 3.4 `p:fileUpload` in a column. However, all file uploads are treated as the same entry. How can I treat file uploads as unique entries?

Comment: I bet BalusC knows the answer.

Comment: Use a `<h:form>` on every row/iteration (in case you use `<ui:repeat>`).

Comment: What performance issues are involved with many forms on a page? I'm just wondering if maybe there's a better way to do it (since my page would, potentially, have 100 forms.

Comment: Well, none. Every form will send its own request. A big form with hundreds of fields, on the other hand, will perform badly.

Comment: Please don't explicitly ask for best practices. This would only sollicit debate and opinions (and confusion). Just state the concrete problem and ask a concrete question. The right answer is already the "best practice".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show any SSCCE, so it's hard to point out the technical mistake, but based on the symptoms, the most probable cause of this problem would be that you've bound all file uploads to one and same bean property. This indeed doesn't make any sense. You need to bind the `<p:fileUpload>` value to the iterated row, not to the parent bean.

E.g. this is wrong:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
    <p:column>
        <p:fileUpload value="#{bean.uploadedFile}">
```

And this is right:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
    <p:column>
        <p:fileUpload value="#{item.uploadedFile}">
```